# Pl/SQL Package Inline Documentation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, documentation-generation

I am attempting to more fully document our database packages as an API. What we would like is something like JavaDocs for PL/SQL. I have seen a couple tools out there (pldoc, plsqldoc) but would like to know from people who use them how they compare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used PlDoc and find it really good. I haven't used any other tools so can't compare. I found PlDoc did the basics well. I wanted some more advanced features so I built our own tool that added extensions to PlDoc for more tags. Also I don't just do documentation with it I also generate our package headers using some PlDoc tags (e.g @private).

I recommend you try PlDoc then tweak whatever doesn't meet your needs. It doesn't take that long to set up so its not a huge time investment to try it.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [NaturalDocs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/)  for a few years now and have found it easy to install and use.
It's pretty much like JavaDocs and supports multiple languages although I've only used it with PL/SQL.
Very configurable although I've not found it necessary to fiddle with that.

Comment: I probably wouldn't have found this particular tool without your answer. While pretty approachable, I think that a more rigidly structured solution is what our team needs. Thanks!